# Get an error during maven clean-install

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I've creates new Spring MVC project. By default Intellij added pom.xml and so on. I have no changes in a default created project , but get an error when clean and install a maven. Please help me to solve this problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUo2E.png)

Comment: You should post code and output as part of the post and not linked to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POM has non-standard characters (whitespace) in your `<artifactId>`. Change it from:

```
<groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
<artifactId>Calc Spring MVC</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

to:

```
<groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
<artifactId>calc-spring-mvn</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

One of the reasons for this constraint is that Maven will potentially resolve dependencies using these coordinates through a URL, where for instance a space character will translate into `%20` which obviously can complicate things.

The official guide does provide some guidance for naming conventions, but is a bit unclear as to what "strange symbols" are. My advice is: use lowercase and hyphens. This is what most people do.

[Guide to naming conventions on groupId, artifactId and version](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html)

Comment: A better answer would explain _why_ this is a disallowed character.

Comment: Fair enough. I have updated the answer with more information. On the other hand, for the answer to be accurate, the question should really have been phrased "Maven artifactId does not match a valid id pattern".

Comment: That's a valid point. In the linked question, I tracked down the part of the code making the validation.

Comment: Ah, excellent! Yes, your original answer to the question you linked to really hit the head on the nail, especially with the regex. Great work!